# Visual Studio 2017: UWP app builds, starts and immediately closes, until VS gets restartet

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

Always and again my Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.2, 26430.6) builds and publishes my UWP C# app ("Publish succeeded") on my PC, starts and immediately closes it again. No errors in output window, a clean doesn't help, no breakpoint (even at earliest possible point in code) gets hit.

It doesn't seem to be related to my program as it happens also with the MS UWP samples, e. g. the Geolocation sample.

It works fine again after restarting VS. Does anyone experience the same behavior?

Comment: Are you launching your app under a debugger? If you do, make sure to set it up to break, when SEH exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes and no, the error occurs either way, started with or without debugger attached. But anyway: Where can I find the option to break on SEH exceptions?

Comment: This is explained under [Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger). Once you have opened the *Exception Settings* window, select *Win32 Exceptions*.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you!

Comment: BTW: I am still having that problem. In case anyone has an idea what's going on here ... !?!

Comment: That wasn't meant to solve the problem. It was a suggestion on how to further analyze it.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, sure. Just wanted to continue search for help since no error gets thrown.

Comment: Looks like a know bug in my Windows 10 Insider version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729716/uwp-fileopenpicker-locks-freezes-app-in-debug