# UWP FileOpenPicker locks\freezes app in debug

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

If the debugger is attached, calling this function causes the app to hang. If I run without a debugger, there is no hang, and file pickers work perfectly.

```
    private async void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    }
```

I'm certain this is something super simple, but I just don't know.

**Edit:**

Here's how I'm using it. Keep in mind, that the simpler function creates the hang issue without all my extra code after it. I've stuffed up the image saving, but that's a separate issue I want to debug when I solve what this post is about.

```
.

   public async Task ImportHeader()
        {
             FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            // For multiple image selection
            var files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile singleImage in files)
            {
                IRandomAccessStream stream = await singleImage.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(stream);
                HeaderImage.Source = image;

                //We also save this to disk for later
                Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("header.jpg", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                stream.Seek(0);

                using (StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().Result))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);

                    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(HeaderImage, (int)HeaderImage.Width, (int)HeaderImage.Height);
                    var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
                    byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();

                    bw.Write(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code sample seems to be missing something. How exactly do you display the file picker dialog?

Comment: I've added the context of the actual code that I'm using. The simpler first line however, recreates the hang without all the other stuff.

Comment: Both of your code samples work fine on my machine, with or without debugger.

Comment: Just for the test, could you make a blank UWP project and execute this line of code `FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();` somewhere in it?

Comment: Are you by any chance on an Insider build? We recently had a bug that slipped through to the insider ring that causes hangs under debug in certain situations, incl file pickers. Please run 'winver' and share the output.

Comment: OS Build 1709 (17025.1000), My non-insider dev machine does not hang!

Comment: @A.Milto That's the very first line of my question above. The additional code below was just added for context.

Comment: @Jarryd Oh, I got it back then and only asked to see if the issue was either related to your current project or affected your whole machine. Glad to know you finally got to the root of the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me as well on some of the recent Windows 10 Insider Preview builds, while the process works flawlessly on stable builds of Windows 10. I think you can assume the cause is there instead of your code.

Comment: Windows Insider PC
1709 (17025.1000)
Picker Hangs

After deploying to a non insider program machine, the picker works as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is a known bug that slipped through into the 17025 insider build. It got fixed in 17027 and above builds.